# Content-Based WCF Router

Tags: wcf-routing

I'm looking for WCF Routers (Content-based and Context-based) examples , please share with me if you have information about content-based wcf router,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about [WCF-Routing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx)?

It:

1. Is WCF [image]
2. Does content-based routing [image]